# Can I call functions and variables from an object's parent class without casting the object's type explicitly?

Tags: c#, inheritance, casting

I want to go through a list of different objects that all derive from sub-classes of the same parent class and i only want to use stuff from the parent class anyways.

```
public class Foo{ public int a=0; }
public class Bar : foo{  }
public class Gun : foo{  }
public class Shotgun : Gun{  }
public class Rifle : Gun{  }
```

then what i would want to do later on:

```
object[] Array ={new Bar(),new Shotgun(),new Rifle()};
int index=0;
foreach(SubclassOfFoo obj in (Array as SubclassOfFoo[]))
{
    (Array[index] as SubclassOfFoo).a++;
    Console.WriteLine(obj.a);

    index++;
}
```

Hopefully there's some way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to declare the array of the parent type:

```
Foo[] Array =new Foo{new Bar(),new Shotgun(),new Rifle()};
```

This way there is no casting required:

```
foreach(Foo obj in Array))
{
    obj.a++;
    Console.WriteLine(obj.a);
}
```

Since all subclasses inherit from `Foo` or from a child of `Foo`, this array can hold all children and grandchildren.
Every subclass will have the property `a`. No casting is required

Answer (score 2):

I would create a collection for base class `Foo` instead of `object`

```
List<Foo> array = new List<Foo>();
array.Add(new Bar());
array.Add(new Shotgun());
array.Add(new Rifle());
```

then you can use the collection directly without casting.

```
foreach(Foo obj in array)
{
    Console.WriteLine(obj.a);
    index++;
}
```